# Getting different App's Hash String every time | SMS Retriever API

Tags: android, android-sms, sms-retriever-api

I am integrating **SMS Retriever API** in my android app.

I followed below docs to generate app's hash string:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string

Following are the ways to generate Hash:
**1) Command**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

2) **AppSignatureHelper class**

I got **different hashes** for **different methods**

> prodRelease(using command) - R2J*******N 
>  prodRelease(using
>   AppSignatureHelper class) - ROI*******6

and also **different hashes** for **different build variants**.

> prodRelease: ROI*******6
>  prodDebug: CAz*******N
>   devRelease: R2J*******N
>  devDebug: ROI*******6 (Same as
>   prodRelease)

I tested my app with SMS template with prodRelease hash i.e **ROI*******6**. It was working great and then after two days, it stopped working. I debug and now the hashes are different again and now it works with different hash **R2J*******N**.

I expect the Hashes to be **same** as it depends on the **app's package id.**
So why different hashes and which Hash to consider correct one or is it going to change every time and I have to keep changing the SMS template in the server?
Or
is there any other better way to be sure about the hash?

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue...

Comment: facing the same issue

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Yo need one hash for every build variant.

1- Debug
2- Release
3- If you sign your app in google play console you need another one, because google change the hash when you upload the app